# Why does Rails sometimes create an asset cache with the wrong permissions?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, permissions, passenger, assets

I have an EC2 instance with the usual stack of Apache, Passenger, and Rails. The app is running in production, so Javascript files are cached into an `all.js` file.

Passenger is configured to pre-start the application instance using the [PassengerPreStart](http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Apache.html#PassengerPreStart) directive.

On occasion, the `all.js` that is created by Rails in `public/javascripts` has the wrong permissions, `0600` for the deployment user. It's supposed to be `0640`, so that Apache can serve the files (they're in the same group, www-data).

Do you have any explanation as to why this is happening? Is there any issue known with `PassengerPreStart` and Rails' asset caching?

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure this is because of the timestamps that come after the assets. If you do a view source the numbers after the asset/files are a timestamp and I think the browsers get confused, or rails messes it up or something.

You change the default of the timestamp to an empty string but putting the following code somewhere in your Rails application.

`/application.rb`

```
ENV[RAILS_ASSET_ID] = ""
```

That will set it to an empty string. See how that goes.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you are suggesting. The asset cache is created at deploy-time by `PassengerPreStart`, not by a user looking at the site. There's no browser involved in this.